# How to check if a number is product of the three sides of Pythagorean triangle?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to check if a number is product of the three sides of Pythagorean triangle?

First few numbers which follows this rules are:

60, 480, 780, 1620, 2040, 3840, 4200,

Comment: You mean, $\exists a,b,c \text{ s.t. } a^2+b^2=c^2, abc=k$

Comment: yes how to check if k is a product of abc

Comment: A necessary condition is that the given number is divisible by $60$

Comment: @Peter Don't forget that for some Pythagorean triples the terms $m^2-n^2,$ $2mn,$ and $m^2+n^2$ all need to be multiplied by a common factor. The cube of this common factor occurs in the product of the terms. There are still only finitely many sets of input to check.

Comment: @Peter What $m$ and $n$ do you choose for the Pythagorean triple $9,12,15$?

Comment: Hm, seems that you are right.

Comment: @Peter But the basic idea of your method still works: just try a finite number of possible combinations.